# Is it possible to bind BorderBrush of a WPF Border to a variable inside ViewModel class?

Tags: c#, wpf, border

Started writing my custom WPF window and I'd like to have colors inside the VM class along with ResizeThickness and all that stuff, to have color scheme editable in settings.

Both of these work:

```
... BorderBrush = "Red" >
... BorderBrush = "{StaticResource [SolidColorBrush from xaml dict]}" >
```

But `... BorderBrush = "{Binding [SolidColorBrush from VM class]" >` does absolutely nothing.

Obviously DataContext is set as said VM class in code of a window constructor.

Second best idea I have is to just edit the xaml and ask for a restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the brush in your viewmodel like this:

```
public System.Windows.Media.Brush MyBrush { get; set; }
```

... and then use it like this:

```
BorderBrush="{Binding MyBrush}"
```

Comment: Yeah. I forgot the `{ get; set; }`. I always forget about the most basic things, guess it just comes with time, huh.

Comment: Ha! Yes - you get bitten by something like this a couple times and it sticks with you. Glad to help!

Comment: A very good guess too! I should totally include the declaration. Is there a difference between variables with and without the get-set or is it specifically tied to ViewModels? (I'm using PropertyChanged by Fody to automatically insert the trigger into set for me)

Comment: Yes, when you use { get; set; } it makes the field a property and PropertyChanged only works with properties. So, if you want to monitor the value of a property in your viewmodel, be sure to make it a property with { get; set;} :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Brush to the ResourceDictionary of a container object and reuse it for all the your controls...

```
<!-- Add the Brush as resource to the surrounding window -->
<Window.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="controlBorderBrush" Color="Gray" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock BorderBrush="{StaticResource controlBorderBrush}" Text="xyz" />
```